# VSTS build: roles keep recycling because they can't locate valid DLLs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My different roles run fine on my local machine. They run well enough when I deploy my project to Azure manually.

However, when I deploy them via VSTS CI/CD tools, the various apps roles refuse to start with "Could not load file or assembly" errors. I'm using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html).

Some of my projects say they can't find a DLL of another project in the solution:

> Unhandled Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'DeviceCloud.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at DeviceCloud.Application.CacheWorker.SimpleInjectionInitializer.RegisterPerWebRequestObjects() ...

Others complain more indirectly. I'm including yet another project, MasterNLogger, that depends on the ILogger interface, so I think what's really going on is it can't locate my MasterNLogger DLL:

> Unhandled Exception: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type ILogger failed. The registered delegate for type ILogger threw an exception. The registered delegate for type ILoggingAdministration threw an exception. Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()...

Why is this working when I deploy manually, and not when I'm deploying with the VSTS tools and build agent?

Comment: Do you have proper assembly binding redirects?

Comment: And how do you deploy, using Build or using Release?

Comment: @abatishchev I'm not sure what you mean. Do I need assembly binding redirects to reference other projects in the solution? And do you mean "debug" or "release" in the build configuration variable? Still feeling my way around VSTS...

Comment: In regards to assemblies, is it a compiler or runtime error?

Comment: In regards to VSTS, it has two core parts: the Build itself and the Release Manager. Which one you're using?

Comment: @abatishchev I think the build. Right now, I'm looking into the binding redirects issue. It may be that my different projects are trying to use different versions of NLog, so I've edited the config files so that they all use the latest version.

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Can you share detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, remove sensitive info from log, then share log)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Here's my debug log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkKP2QDfi8r_as6Aymqer8ZEi_o . I think the relevant part is where it's trying to include MasterNLogger, which depends on NLog.dll, and for some reason can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add task(s) before build task to restore the packages:

1. Add NuGet Tool Installer task to build definition (Version of NuGet.exe to install: `4.4.1`)
2. Add NuGet restore task (Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: `**\*.sln`)

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. Here's my output log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkKP2QDfi8r_a4O-UVoxI-xZgzw . How did you know to use 4.4.1, by the way?

Comment: Okay, I've fixed my errors by applying NuGet packages required by projects that I reference. I am still curious though as to why 4.4.1 is the version I need. Either way, it works now! Thanks for your help.